# What to do so my parents don't get divorced?

Tags: teen, divorce

I am 14 years old and my parents are planning to divorce, the one who wants a divorce is my mother, she says that because of my father's behavior she really doesn't care anymore if something happens to him, it was also because of a message she saw on his cell phone from someone saying “my love”, I really don't know if my dad cheated on her but my dad has told me that he would never divorce my mom because he married her for a reason. I really love my parents and I don't know how I could live with them apart even though it would be for the “good”.

Comment: Something like this requires marriage counseling, i'm afraid there is little that you can do.

Comment: Welcome! We do get this question occasionally and in short - there’s nothing _you_ can do. A marriage is between two adults and _they_ need to find a solution, or not. You can of course voice your concerns and it’s their responsibility as parents to find a solution to make the process easier for you and find a viable solution for the future.

Comment: First of all, as @Stephie mentioned, it’s not your fault. Your parents are responsible for loving each other and providing you a loving and safe environment. If there is abuse, seek help from a trusted adult to help you get out of the situation. Otherwise, let them know you love them both. Help them realize that divorce doesn’t automatically solve problems and it can complicate things, especially with you in the middle. Some companies partner with a counseling service and many churches have free counseling available, so your parents may be able to at least start counseling for free.